# Setting store id for products at admin

Tags: magento-1.8, product, admin, event-observer, store-view

I have different stores under same website in my magento admin. I would like to add products specific to some stores. But I'm unable to do it. Under the website option in add new product if I select main website, then it is avaibable for all stores. How to add products to specific stores alone?

Since I knew my store ids I tried setting them using observer event catalog_product_save_after. But it dint work.

Can anyone help?

Following is my observer function. If I try the below one, the page keeps on loading without stopping.

```
public function catalogProductSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    $product->setStoreId('3')->save();      

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Products can be assigned only for websites, not store views.
If you want you can overcome this, but setting the products 'Not visible individually' on the stores you don't want them to appear.
You can do this by using the `Update Attributes` option from the product grid or by code like this:

Create an array with all your product ids that you don't want displayed in some stores and and array with those stores.

```
$productIds = array(....);//product ids here
$storeIds = array(....);//banned store ids here

foreach ($storeIds as $storeId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttribtues(
        $productIds,
        array('visibility' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE),
        $storeId
    );
}
```

Clear the cache and rebuild your indexes.